# How to mirror docker volumes in host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

As far as I understand, we have 3 kinds of entities:

1. Containers
2. Host
3. Volumes

We can map

1. a host directory to one or more containers
2. a volume to one or more containers

but how about maping a volume to one or more directories on the host machine? so we can effectively create multiple live mirrors of the volume?

Here's my last attempt:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mirroring-container:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - important-data:/home
      - ./mirror1:/home
      - ./mirror2:/home
      - ./mirror3:/home
volumes:
  important-data:
```

I was expecting that this way, any files created inside the /home directory in the nginx container will also be created in 4 other locations:

1. important-data volume
2. folder mirror1 in the host directory containing the docker-compose.yml
3. folder mirror2 in the host directory containing the docker-compose.yml
4. folder mirror3 in the host directory containing the docker-compose.yml

However, for some reason, docker ignored all of these except the last one. Once I created a file in the /home directory of the container, it was created only in the mirror3 folder, it wasn't event created in the volume.

Comment: You observed behaviour is the expected (and documented) behaviour. If you want multiple copies of the files you need to actually copy the data to multiple locations. AFAIK there is no built-in way to do that in docker and the solution suited is most likely going to depend on your requirements.

Comment: Also just a note just to nitpick a little. Docker didn't ignore the other volumes. It's just that you can only mount one thing in one location at a time. Mounting a second thing in the same place will effectively hide the previous mount.

Comment: I don't want to copy files once. I want to mirror them, ie a live replication of the folder so that all changes are automatically replicated in all folders at the moment it happens. 

Is there anyway I can do this with docker?

Comment: No, there is not. You need some other tool to take care of that for you.

Comment: (You can do with Docker volumes pretty much exactly what you can do with the normal Linux mount(8) command.)

Comment: You can have several softlinks to the same directory on your host. That way you can access the same files in multiple locations. But they are ultimately the same files, not mirrors of each other.

Comment: I see. Oh, that's dissapointing :( but thank you for the explanation :) it helps

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not support that feature. In Linux the closest thing i can figure it is to use raid1, but this is "low level" and not managed by docker